# Ubuntu 13.04 + Gnome 3.8 input switch keyboard shortcut

Tags: gnome, language-support, input-language

I'm trying to setup a keyboard shortcut to change the input language on my Ubuntu 13.04 running gnome 3.8.

I don't really care which service handles this, as long as I can <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> to change inputs, and have an indication of which language is currently used in the taskbar.

I'd love for some guidance from someone who got it working.
Thanks!

Comment: Actually, how did you installed Gnome 3.8 in Ubuntu Raring? If you are using the PPA, is better just to uninstall it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1184564) in Ubuntu 13.04. You might be able to fix it by using the [Gnome3 PPA](https://launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/+archive/gnome3), but I haven't tried myself.